# create-react-app not working after installing yarn and npx working

Tags: reactjs, yarnpkg

I am a new mac user I just have bought a mac m1 and I have a strange problem.
i have yarn v3 installed when i try to run command

```
yarn create-react-app app
```

it gives me this error

```
Usage Error: The project in /Users/home/package.json doesn't seem to have been installed - running an install there might help
```

Comment: yarn/npx create-react-app app should have created a project named app in the directory you ran the command. Once you generated the project you need to cd into it and run npm/yarn start

Comment: This works for windows: yarn create react-app my-app. Is it different for Mac?

Comment: @ArmanEbrahimi it is an error in my laptop i has an old version of yarn v 1.22 but i wan to upgrade it to v3 to be able to use latest pacakges

Comment: Do you have a yarn.lock at /Users/home/ ? Try deleting it. Some other relevant info at https://github.com/yarnpkg/berry/issues/625

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'create-react-app' is a toolkit to quickly create a React app with some boilerplate code.

You can create a React app in 2 steps:

Step 1: install create-react-app

Step 2: use create-react-app to create your app.

For step 1:
To install create-react-app use the following command:

```
yarn global add create-react-app
```

For step 2: To use this to create your React app:

```
create-react-app app
```

You can also create the app without globally installing the 'create-react-app' package:

```
npx create-react-app <app name>
```

For your reference: https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html#create-react-app